# Crontab crash when running a script that insert a lot of lines in MySQL

Tags: ubuntu, cron

My crontab is crashing when I run a script that inserts a lot of lines on MySQL Database, but when I run a script that inserts a few lines it runs properly. Is there some configuration file of cron? Maybe some config about use of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the reason of the script crashing. Here are some points to check:

1. Make sure you don't have multiple running instances of the same script. This is especially useful if you are running the script for a long time and/or too frequently.
2. Include some debug information in the script whenever relevant. This helps you determines where the script got stopped.
3. Split the insert statements into multiple iterations if possible.

Comment: i fixed it, it was mysql memory usage. I installed a newest version and it get fixed. I was using a older MySQL Version

Answer (score 0):

Using a cron job to insert "don't know how many" rows into MySQL is bad design.

First of all determine if the cron jobs get enough time to finish the insert, by proper logging outside of the normal cron process.

Then, when you have determined that yes, it does take too much time, reduce the frequency of the cron job, or reduce the number of inserts during one run.